# Get a specific AD Group membership then export to csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of computers that I need to find a specific AD Group Membership and output to csv.

How can I do this from PS ?

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership (Get-ADComputer ComputerName) | select-object name
```

Thanks you

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code. HINT: a `ForEach` loop is what you want to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not trying to find groups of users, but computers. using `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` is useless.

```
Get-Content .\ListOfComputer.txt | Get-ADComputer -properties Memberof 
| Where-Object {$_.MemberOf -like "*Specific Word*"} | export-csv SpecificADGroupMembership.csv -Append
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I filter the result so that there are only groups containing a specific word ?

Comment: Warning: Please don't user any `set-*` commands until you understand how PowerShell works. Adding a `Where-Object` is a simple filter.

Comment: Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property MemberOf | Where-Object { $_.MemberOf -Like "*APP*"} | ForEach { $_.Name } | export-csv SpecificADGroupMembership.csv